# Channel Images database error

Tags: channel-images

I have Channel Images 7.0.0 installed on EE 3.5.16 (MSM). If I go to Channel Images settings I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database-name.exp_channels_channel_fields' doesn't exist:
>   SELECT `cf`.`field_id`, `cf`.`field_label`, `ff`.`group_name` FROM (`exp_channel_fields` cf) LEFT JOIN `exp_channels_channel_fields` ct ON `ct`.`field_id` = `cf`.`field_id` LEFT JOIN `exp_channels_channel_field_groups` fg ON `fg`.`channel_id` = `ct`.`channel_id` LEFT JOIN `exp_field_groups` ff ON `ff`.`group_id` = `fg`.`group_id` WHERE `cf`.`site_id` = 1 AND `cf`.`field_type` = 'channel_images'
>
> ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122

I have tried contacting EEHarbor (aquired DevDemon), but I'm getting no response. Can anyone shed some light on the cause / solution to this error?

Comment: I have the same error in EE3. Did you get any solution for it?

Comment: I received this from EEHarbor support: "We looked through the code and it looks like the error you're getting is specific to the Channel Images 7.0.0 version which is for EE4 only. For EE3, you will need to install the 6.0.4 version."

Comment: Yeah, it could be. Because I am checking in the EE3. I will check it in EE4. Thanks for this information. You can also add the above comment as an answer.